# How can I create the libtesseract shared object file in Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: compilation, tesseract, building

OK, so I have built tesseract 5.3.1 and leptonica 1.84 from source, but cannot for the life of me find the magic incantation to build the libtesseract.so file.
Either I get a load of undefined references e.g.

> ./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `tesseract::StrideMap::ReduceWidthTo1()'

Or it tells me to use -fPIC (again lots of similar messages)

> relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I have tried configuring the build of leptonica with all the combinations of options I can think of...

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-shared --enable-static --with-zlib --with-jpeg --with-libwebp  --with-libtiff --with-libpng
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-static --with-zlib --with-jpeg --with-libwebp  --with-libtiff --with-libpng
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-zlib --with-jpeg --with-libwebp  --with-libtiff --with-libpng
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-zlib --with-jpeg --with-libwebp  --with-libtiff --with-libpng --with-pic=yes

And for tesseract, once I've built leptonica, the same, try every combination imaginable...except of course I have figured that if I specify disable-shared, it doesn't even try to build the .so file! :-)

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib/ --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/lib/ --with-pic=yes
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib/ --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/lib/
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-static --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib/ --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/lib/ --with-pic=yes

I was expecting to be able to build a libtesseract.so file ...

Is someone able to point me in the right direction? I'm sure the answer is very simple in the end.. I'm guessing I need to point the tesseract build to the leptonica libs (but I thought I'd done that with the --prefix??)

OK, I've also tried taking the tesseract-tesseract.o file and creating a .so file from it but still get nagged to use -fPIC despite the fact I've used --with-pic=yes for both leptonica and tesseract:

> gcc -shared -o tesseract-tesseract.so tesseract-tesseract.o
> /usr/bin/ld: tesseract-tesseract.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against
> `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object;
> recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable
> section on output collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks in advance!
YoungJules